# How to color a column in this table?

Tags: tables, color

I have this table and would like to change the color of the cells. I have defined the colors "Orange", "DarkGrey", and "lightGrey". I made the top title row in orange, and would like the remaining cells in the first column to be dark grey, and the remaining cells in every other column be light grey. How can I do this?

```
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth} { 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | }

  \hline

  \rowcolor{Orange}\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Title}}} \\

 \hline

 item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\

 \hline

 item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\

\hline

\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Do you want to colour the columns background or the text in the columns?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to colour the background, here you are:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \begin{document}

    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth} {
      | >{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{DarkGrey}}X
      | >{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{LightGrey}}X
      | >{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{LightGrey}}X | }
      \hline
      \rowcolor{Orange}\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Title}}} \\
     \hline
     item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
     \hline
     item 21 & item 22 & item 23 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the package tabularray

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}
        {
            hlines,vlines,
            colspec=*{3}{X[c,bg=gray!25]},
            column{1} = {bg=gray!75},
            row{1} = {bg=orange, fg=white, font=\bfseries},
            cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{c},%<-- the multicol
        }

        Title\\
        item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
        item 21 & item 22 & item 23
    \end{tblr}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{X[c]X[c]X[c]}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
    \columncolor{gray!75}{1}
    \columncolor{gray!25}{2,3}
    \rowcolor{orange}{1}
\Body
    \Block{1-3}{\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries Title}\\
    item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
    item 21 & item 22 & item 23
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]